# Not a directory but have contents

Tags: python, directory, youtube-dl

So I use Compute Engine VM in Google Cloud to download youtube videos. I use Youtube-dl  to download it. I follow the documentation in here: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#how-do-i-update-youtube-dl

After I install youtube-dl and try to run it, I found an error:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 1794, in _real_extract
    'uploader_id': self._search_regex(r'/(?:channel|user)/([^/?&#]+)', owner_profile_url, 'uploader id') if owner_profile_url else None,
```

A simple error, and I know how to fix this. I just need to head into `/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py` and look at line 1794

The thing is, when I try to nano the address, it's not a directory.

[image]

It makes me confuse. It literally said that I have error in that directory but now that's not a directory. I use this to install youtube-dl:

```
sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

I try to add write acc with `sudo chmod +w /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl` but I still can't edit it.

Can anyone explain why it's not a directory when it said that it's in the error message? And how to access it?

Edit:
I try `ls -lad youtube-dl` and get:

`-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1837828 Jul 13 07:58 youtube-dl`

Also `file youtube-dl` and get:

`youtube-dl: a /usr/bin/env python script executable (binary data)`

Comment: what are the outputs of `ls -lad youtube-dl` and without `-d`. Maybe also `file youtube-dl`

Comment: That looks like what you'd expect from [a Python egg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2051192/2072269)

Comment: Or not, it might actually be this instead: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html

Comment: @FelixJN, I try it and get: ```-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1837828 Jul 13 07:58 youtube-dl``` Also file youtube-dl return ```youtube-dl: a /usr/bin/env python script executable (binary data)```

Comment: Please (a) [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397), (b) don't put updates in comments where they can missed. Make your question a [self-contained whole](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/751378/edit) so it's easy for people to read and answer